# Can we do like this https://en-ae.namshi.com/buy-amongst-few-year-of-the-horse-t-shirt-for-men-t-shirts-125976.html

Tags: magento-1.8, product, configurable-product

Go to above link you can see under colors attributes have 2 option white & black. it is separate products.

then search this product name 'AMONGST FEW' you can see 2 products in there white & black.

click white product one then you can see both t-shirts in under color.

can i create a configurable product like this ? urgent quick help me.

Comment: Please don't put full links like that in your title. Describe your issue shortly in your title so people will know what your question is about (without clicking the link).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can create a configurable product And create two simple product ans associate these. when you create configurable product you must select supper attribute as color.

See [Configurable Product Example](http://ultimo.infortis-themes.com/demo/default/dress7.html)

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, you want a white t-shirt product & a black t-shirt product which will show separately, when you search. And if you view these products, you can choose different colors as well.

Yes, you can create two configurable product with white & black options.
That means you need to create 4 simple products (two black & two white t-shirts) & 2 Configurable products. And in those configurable products assign white picture to one & black to another one.

Comment: thanks, can you send me wireframe ? then i can understand.

Comment: can i do that ColorSwatchesPro plugin ?

Comment: yes, you can definitely use that